# In standard tuning, does guitar string 6 produce E3 or E2?

Tags: guitar

I am finding confusing information concerning guitar string 6's frequency.  Many articles claim it to be E2. How can it be E2 when string 6 is E below middle C which is E3?

Comment: Given, that there are several octave numbering schemes, this is hard to answer. But the interval between strings is constant, so which octave has your fifth string?

Comment: See also: [Why is guitar music written one octave higher?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/101432/70803).

Comment: @guidot I think it’s clear from context that the asker considers middle C to be C4.

Comment: I am going by the common expression that middle C is C4 261.6 Hz.

Comment: To be more clear, is string 5 fret 3 not the frequency of middle C?

Comment: @ejbpesca No, that's the small c, or C3, an octave lower. If you want to play a middle C, go to the B string, fret 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Empty guitar strings are:

- great E, aka E<sub>2</sub>, ~82.4 Hz
- great A, aka A<sub>2</sub>, 110 Hz
- small d, aka D<sub>3</sub>, ~147 Hz
- small g, aka G<sub>3</sub>, ~196 Hz
- small b, aka B<sub>3</sub>, ~247 Hz
- one-lined e', aka E<sub>4</sub>, ~330 Hz

Neither the high E nor the low E string is the small e (E<sub>3</sub>).
The high E (string 1) is the one-lined e' (E<sub>4</sub>), a major third above middle C and a fourth below chamber A.
The low E (string 6) is the great E (E<sub>2</sub>).

Comment: This answer addresses the question without any extraneous information. Thank you.

Comment: Great E? Small D? One-lined E? This is a notation I've never heard of before; I'd be interested in learning more about it. Is it a guitar-specific thing, or a regional thing, or what?

Comment: @Hearth Regional, it seems. I'm afraid the numbered notation feels rather foreign to me in turn - that is something I've seen at the English-speaking internet and nowhere else. Wikipedia has [an article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_pitch_notation), and a handy table in the [Octave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octave#Octave_of_a_pitch) article.

Comment: @Divizna I had no idea Helmholtz did research into acoustic physics; I know of him for a few contributions to my field, electrical engineering. You say english-speaking; what language does your notation usually get used in? I'd guess German, as Helmholtz was German?

Comment: @Hearth I don't know. It's definitely the unambiguous standard in my country, and unsurprisingly, it [seems to be](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oktave#Untergliederung_des_Tonraumes_in_Oktavr%C3%A4ume) the standard for German-speaking places, too. Other than that, beats me. If I were to guess, I'd place my bet on "the entire northern half of Europe from British Isles to Russia", but it's really just a largely uninformed guess and I may be completely wrong.

Comment: @Divizna - I haven't seen it used like that in Britain, so maybe not :-)

Answer (score 17):

The guitar is a quasi-transposing instrument because it sounds an octave lower than written. When we read E3 on a score and then play the lowest string on the guitar, the sound that comes out is E2. When we read middle C on the score and play the third fret of the A string the sound that comes out is C3.

For transposing instruments, each fingering has **two** pitches related to it. There’s the “written” pitch, which means when we see that note in sheet music, we play that fingering. The other pitch related to a specific fingering is the “concert” pitch, which is the pitch (similar to frequency) that we hear coming from the instrument as the actual sound.

On the guitar, every fingering has a concert pitch that is an octave lower than the written pitch. So when we see middle C written on the page, we play the fifth string, third fret. And when we play that, what we hear is an octave below middle C.

Since every string and fret combination on guitar has two pitches associated with it, we have to give two answers to the question “is string five, fret 3 middle C?” It is and it isn’t. It is middle C written, but it’s an octave below middle C concert.

Comment: To be more concrete the guitar is what we consider a tenor instrument, which are notated in treble clef but sound an octave lower.

Comment: Why the phrase  “quasi-transposing”? “Octave transposing” is a standard phrase and description for instruments like guitar, flute and piccolo to name a few.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy There’s no way to talk about guitar transposition without getting criticism for the terminology used, so I made up my own term - not to avoid criticism, but to own the criticism.

Comment: @ToddWilcox No criticism intended, just a query. Whenever I hear something unfamiliar related to music I like to find out if I’ve missed something.

Comment: Oh, in my previous comment I meant to type “bass”, not “flute”. I missed the 5 minute edit window for comments…by 2.5 hours

Comment: It's a 'transposing instrument'.  More specifically, an 'octave transposing instrument'.   Nothing quasi about it.

Comment: I am referring to E2 and E3 as frequencies.  They both are not the same.  Is string 5 fret 3 not middle C = 261.6 Hz?

Comment: @ejbpesca When you see middle C written on the page, you play string 5, fret 3. When you play string 5, fret 3, what comes out of the guitar is the C an octave below middle C. That is normal and it is how the guitar works. Technically, E2, E3, and middle C are not frequencies, they are *pitches*. Pitches are related to frequencies but they are different.

Comment: I found a chart giving a frequency value to the alphanumeric designation of C4 of 261.6 Hz and C4 as piano key in the middle of the keyboard calling that middle C.   Is string 5 fret 3 not middle C/C4?  If not, what key on the piano is its equivalent?

Comment: @ejbpesca “Is string 5 fret 3 not middle C/C4?” Yes and no. It both **is** middle C and it **isn’t** middle C at the sand time. We call it “middle C” and we write down middle C on staff paper when we want a guitarist to play fret 3 string 5. But when the guitarist plays that note, we don’t hear middle C. What we hear is the C one octave below middle C, C3. That’s what “transposing” means.

Comment: In a sane world, guitar would be notated with an explicit octave-shifted treble clef — with a small subscript ‘8’ to indicate that the notes sound an octave lower than written — and there would be no ambiguity (nor any need to pretend that it's a transposing instrument)…

Comment: @gidds If the clef with the 8 at the bottom is used, then the guitar doesn’t sound an octave lower than written, because that clef indicates to play an octave lower than treble clef. That would be a way for guitarists to read the same way they read now and no longer be playing a transposing instrument.

Comment: There are no transposing instruments. There is only transposing notation. And yes, it should be a treble clef with an 8 subscript.

Answer (score 11):

Guitar is written in treble clef, but sounds an octave lower than written.   Sometimes we use the 'treble (down 8)' clef which makes this transposition explicit.

There are (at least) two numbering conventions for pitch.  One of them calls Middle C 'C4'.  Another calls it 'C3'.  But whatever you call it, guitar sounds one octave lower.
[image]

Comment: Is there a functional purpose to not placing  guitar notes to the staff at the correct position of their sound?

Comment: @ejbpesca Yes, you want them in the staff where they can be easily read, not a messy bunch of ledger lines below.

Comment: @Divizna That makes sense as to why you wouldn't write them as-heard on a treble clef. But for me, it just shifts the question - why not place the notes in the correct position on a bass clef? No extra ledger lines required.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I guess because way fewer people are literate in the bass clef than treble. (And when a guitarist makes the effort to learn a second system, they're likely to go with tabs.)

Comment: @NuclearHoagie treble clef is actually optimal in terms of the number of ledger lines needed to notate lots of guitar music, see https://music.stackexchange.com/q/101432/63781 and https://music.stackexchange.com/q/118892/63781

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Putting guitar on bass clef would require a ridiculous number of ledger lines above the bass clef for the higher octaves of the guitar. Treble clef means three ledger lines down to the lowest E on the guitar and three ledger lines above for the highest E. It’s kinda perfect for the guitar’s range.

Answer (score 1):

In standard tuning guitar string 6 produces E2.